# Is there a region change hook in emacs lisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm trying to get the content of current selected region in buffer. I'm aware of idle timer, but a hook should be more efficient/cleaner...

Comment: Just to clarify, since I can't edit my question, what I want to achieve is the selected region whenever the region change (either with mouse or keyboard...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to go seems to advice `handle-shift-selection`. AFAICT this function is called with every region-change by keyboard. Resp. advice `mouse-drag-region`.

Comment: ```emacs-lisp
(defadvice handle-shift-selection (after my-show-point-and-mark () activate)
  "Show point and mark."
  (message "[%s %s]" (mark) (point)))
```

Thanks Andreas, almost. It works when I move cursor by keyboard, but not with the mouse...

Comment: @QuangLinhLe Great it works so far - extended the answer WRT moves by mouse.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by "region change".  If you mean "the text in the region is modified", then you'll need to use `after-change-functions`.  If you mean that the selected text is modified by changing its bounds, then you'll probably want `post-command-hook` or maybe an idle timer (which is not less efficient than a hook, the main difference is that you get less guarantees about when it gets run; e.g. it won't be run between two commands if there's no idle time between the two, as is the case when running a keyboard macro).

Comment: Sorry for an obscure question I mean when `region-beginning` and/or `region-end` change, not the selected text...

Comment: ⁺¹: even though `post-command-hook` is a clear overkill, but it seems the only way to deal with that.